# Best practice for mounting drive on logon

Tags: hard-drive, mount, sd-card

I have a MBP 2015, and use the SD card slot for a second drive; it's a slow micro SD card, but I only use it for backups, which suits my purpose.

I've noticed that since upgrading to OS 10.13, the drive no longer mounts on logon, and I was wondering how to solve that? If I physically remove and re-insert the drive, it loads up, and it's formatted as Mac OS extended, case sensitive, journaled and encrypted. It has no errors from Disk Utility, First Aid check.

So, should I write an AppleScript, add it to my start up items, add it to fstab? Seeking the best practice (or best way?) to mount this drive when I login.